# I have setup apache tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I have setup apache tomcat 8.5.15

I have tried start and stop, clear cache, checked log files , configured JDK environment perfectly but I will not start and the localhost:9999 gives error in connection.

The log files also don't show any error?
What is the solution?

why doesn't it works?

Comment: Is there any console output?

Comment: Standard port for tomcat is 8080 not 9999

Comment: Grammar and spaces

Answer (score 0):

I would go so far as to say, check the port within the '/conf/server.xml' to check what port it is using.